# Creating A Javascript MultiDimentional Array From input data values

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I am working with some number of Number fields on a table.The table contains Item Name, Unit Price and Number Filed which is Quantity.Each Time Amount is increased or decreased i want an array of products/items which will contain `item name`, `item unit price`, `item Amount` , `total price of that item`.

### For example like this

```
items = 
 [
    ['Name', '5', '2', '10'],
    ['Name2', '15', '2', '30'],
 ]
```

If amount is `zero` Then that item will not take place in the array.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(document).on('input', '.se-ticket-qty', function() {
    var items = GetItems();

    // jQuery('input#items').val(items);
    console.log(items);
  });

  function GetItems() {
    jQuery(".se-ticket-qty").each(function(index) {
      var items = [];
      var item_name = jQuery(this).data('name');
      var unit_price = parseFloat(jQuery(this).data('unit-price'));
      var amount = parseFloat(jQuery(this).val());
      var totalPrice = unit_price * amount;

      items = [item_name, unit_price, amount, totalPrice];
    });
    return items;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Front Row</th>
    <td><span class="se-curency">$ </span>5</td>
    <td>
      <input min="0" data-name="Front Row" data-unit-price="5" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>VIP Seat</th>
    <td><span class="se-curency">$ </span>10</td>
    <td>
      <input min="0" data-name="VIP Seat" data-unit-price="10" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reassigning `items` to a new Array

1. Initialize array outside each block
2. Use [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to populate new array Element
3. Use *camelCase*  i.e. `unitPrice` for dashed keys when using `.data()` method.
4. Add condition statement for *zero*

*Code*

```js
function GetItems() {
  var items = []; //Initialize 
  jQuery(".se-ticket-qty").each(function(index) {
    var item_name = jQuery(this).data('name');
    var unit_price = parseFloat(jQuery(this).data('unitPrice'));
    var amount = parseFloat(jQuery(this).val());
    //Add condtion for zero
    if (amount > 0) { 
      var totalPrice = unit_price * amount;
      items.push([item_name, unit_price, amount, totalPrice]); //Use push
    }
  });
  return items;
}

jQuery(document).on('input', '.se-ticket-qty', function() {
  var items = GetItems();

  console.clear();
  console.log(items);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Front Row</th>
    <td><span class="se-curency">$ </span>5</td>
    <td>
      <input min="0" data-name="Front Row" data-unit-price="5" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>VIP Seat</th>
    <td><span class="se-curency">$ </span>10</td>
    <td>
      <input min="0" data-name="VIP Seat" data-unit-price="10" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```